# Mod rewrite location header contains root file path

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I'm trying to rewrite

`https://example.com/vehicles.php?id=42` to `https://example.com/vehicles/brand/honda`

to handle my new URL change without affecting SEO. (i.e. "42" should be mapped to "honda")

I tried [this](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/introduction-to-url-rewriting/).

```
RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING}  ^id=42$                   
RewriteRule  ^vehicles.php$  ^vehicles/brand/honda$    [L,R=301]   #to handle old URLs to new URL mapping
RewriteRule  ^vehicles/brand/honda$   ^vehicles.php?id=42$   [L]  #to handle URL to file mapping
```

But it redirects to

`https://example.com/root/site/%5evehicles/brand/honda$?id=42` which is incorrect in 2 ways.

1. It includes a file path (`/root/site`)
2. I want the query param to be dropped.

I appreciate some help to get this fixed.

Comment: Your RewriteRule is inverted, it should be something like `RewriteRule ^vehicles/brand/honda$ vehicles.php$`.

Comment: That redirection is already there with another rule. I just want to redirect my old SEOed URLs such as `https://example.com/vehicles.php?id=42` to the new URL scheme which is `https://example.com/vehicles/brand/honda`. Is it clear? I updated the rule above to show both.

Comment: Why are you using regular expression anchoring syntax in the _substitution_ URL? That makes no sense at all. `^` and `$` have absolutely no business being there.

Comment: That's right. I got it from this blog post. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/introduction-to-url-rewriting/ but removed the regex part from it.

Answer (score 1):

Character `?` at the end of line removes query string from output path.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=42$
RewriteRule  ^vehicles.php$  vehicles/brand/honda?    [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Great. This solved problem 2 above. Thank you. Any idea about the problem 1?

Comment: I don't think it's related to the .htaccess file, however you can always type `RewriteRule  ^vehicles.php$  http://example.com/vehicles/brand/honda?    [L,R=301]`

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with that solution until I find the root cause.